# What's the good of Marker Interface?

Tags: design-patterns, marker-interfaces

The idea or purpose of the marker interface sounds totally meaningless to me.

While searching for the "Serializable Class" in Java, I inevitably came to this concept, 'Marker Interface'. I understood why and when to use it - to tag/mark the class that it is for special usage, like serialization.

But the biggest point here is that the reason itself, I mean idea of marking the class to indicate that we'll use it for some usage but WITHOUT any method, seems quite a nonsense to me.

If we want to endow a class some special meanings so that it can perform the jobs we aim to, I strongly believe that it should contain methods written for that jobs. If it contains nothing inside, that what makes it different from the plain class? I can even put "implements Serializable" to any classes not intended to serialize..

To summarize- What's the GOOD  of the Marker Interface?

Answer (score 0):

Marker Interfaces are only used for type identification. Other than that there is no specific usage for Marker Interface.

For example as you mentioned Serializable is a good example of Marker interface without any function. The Classes which implemented the Serializable and their objects are identified for serialization process by the JVM.

So if we want to Identify the Object type to do any specific operation. We can create our own Marker interfaces and use it.

Comment: [About Marker Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) refer this @rhee

Answer (score 0):

Marker interface really should be avoided.

There are ways in which to get the same thing done without a marker interface as one would with a marker interface and those methods definitely should be preferred as a marker interface is regarded as somewhat of a code smell.

In C# one can use attributes that may be applied to a class.  These are definitely slower though as doing a safe cast is rather quick but there are ways one could improve the speed through caching based on the input type for instance.

I find that using a plain `object` in many instances, as opposed to expecting a marker interface, may be more flexible in that is places less of a burden on the implementer.

There really is no need for a marker interface.

Answer (score 0):

Marker interfaces were originally used to attach special meaning to a class before Java had introduced annotations (in JDK 5). For example, the [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface was created in JDK 1.1. With the introduction of annotations, a better approach—if a class needs to be marked and no additional methods are needed—is to use annotations.

For example, instead of having a class implement the `Serializable` interface, which has no methods, a better approach would be to create an annotation, `@Serializable`, and apply that annotation to a class (note that `@Serializable` is *not* a real annotation included in the JDK).

```
@Serializable
public class Foo {}
```

For more information on how to create and process annotations, please see [Creating Annotations in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-annotations-in-java) (pardon that I authored that article; it encompasses the information you would need to know about annotation processing without cluttering this answer by copying it directly here).

---

Another approach would be to change the thought process behind the marker interface and instead of processing classes and performing actions based on their markers, pushing the logic to the class itself. For example, instead of looking for classes with `Serializable` and then performing logic, the logic could be moved directly to the `Serializable` interface, allowing clients to call the serialization logic directly on the object. For example:

```
public interface Serializable {

    public default void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        // ... default logic ...
    }

    public default void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // ... default logic ...
    }

    public default void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
        // ... default logic ...
    }
}
```

Then a serializable object can be serialized directly:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {}

ObjectOutputStream os = // ... some output stream
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.writeObject(os);
```

Answer (score 0):

A marker interface is used to add support to a class for functionality that is *not* implemented by overriding methods.

When you declare that a class implements `Serializable` or `Cloneable`, for example, you are allowing it to be passed to methods that require these types, and promising that it adheres to the contract of those types via the Liskov Substitution Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

There is more to an interface's implied contract than just the methods it makes you override.

Marker interfaces are pretty rare, since its almost always better for the functionality required by an interface to be implemented with interface methods.  Occasionally, as is the case for `Serializable` and `Cloneable`, however, it just doesn't fit that pattern for some reason.  A marker interface is used in these cases, because the other functions of an interface are still valid.